# Training model with batches of training data-R

Tags: r, training-data, sequential

I am new to R and data analysis.
I am hitting the wall as my hardware is not able to process the whole training set for computing a model.

I was thinking by using the caret package, am I able to train the model by breaking the training data in batches i.e. training the model with the first 1000 rows, followed by the next 1000 rows and so on and so forth?  I then will be able to trim the model at every stage to save memory.

Will the model be “updated” with every feed of the batch of training data?

I know this method is known as sequential training but wasn’t able to find a practical example/case study.

Hope to get some guidance on this.  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some information regarding the size of your data. Number of rows in the data.frame or size of data in MB/GBs.

Comment: My training data is over a million rows, with 14 variables.  I am trying to run some computation on my 8GB laptop and decided to try this method before breaking the bank to invest in a better machine.  Size of file is over 400MB.

Comment: which function from the `caret` package did you use to train the model? I don't think that the model will be updated with every feed of the batch of training data. You can do sampling to train your model on a smaller subset and see what kind of results you are getting for a start.